# mysql---how to design the guestbook database?

Tags: php, mysql, database

i am a new learner of php, now, i want to write a guestbook. but i don't know how to  design the guestbook database. expect someone can give me some datails about it. the  guestbook table  i want to be (guest message, admin reply guest message,guest info). how to  design these tablle's fields.

Comment: The question is too vague to be able to provide a meaningful answer. I'm guessing you'll need at least 2 tables - one to store the messages and one to store the admin users, but without more information it's hard to say for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you don't have a clear picture of what you want. That makes it hard to offer any usable advice.

There are plenty of sites offering free guestbooks (php/mysql). You can download the code and dissect it to learn from it and get ideas for your own guestbook.

For example, [HotScripts](http://www.hotscripts.com/category/php/scripts-programs/guestbooks) have listed 395 guestbooks.

Have a look and come back with a more specific question, and I promise that people will help you with specific problems.

Answer (score 1):

At this point, its very unclear. With the information you have provided, all I can say is if you want to create a guestbook tabble with the fields you mentioned, you can do it this way -

```
CREATE TABLE Guestbook (
  guestbook_id int(11) default NULL auto_increment,
  guestinfo varchar(60) default NULL,
  guestmessage varchar(60) default NULL,
  adminreply varchar(60) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (guestbook_id)
) TYPE=MyISAM
```